# Injecting Dependency into Web API Controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, dependency-injection, unity-container

I want to inject unity container into WebController.

I have UnityDependencyResolver:

```
public class UnityDependencyResolver : IDependencyResolver
{
    readonly IUnityContainer _container;

    public UnityDependencyResolver(IUnityContainer container)
    {
    this._container = container;
    }

    public object GetService(Type serviceType)
    {
        try
        {
            return _container.Resolve(serviceType);
        }
        catch
        {
            return null;
        }
    }

    public IEnumerable<object> GetServices(Type serviceType)
    {
        try
        {
            return _container.ResolveAll(serviceType);
        }
        catch
        {
            return new List<object>();
        }
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _container.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Then, in my Global.asax I add the following line:

```
var container = new UnityContainer();
container.RegisterType<IService, Service>
(new PerThreadLifetimeManager()).RegisterType<IDALContext, DALContext>();
DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new UnityDependencyResolver(container));
```

Then, If I use the following in a Web Controller:

```
private IService _service;

public HomeController(IService srv)
{
    _service = srv;
}
```

It works fine.

But I want to inject it into WebAPI Controller, so if I do it the same way:

```
private IService _service;

public ValuesController(IService srv)
{
    _service = srv;
}
```

It does not work, it says that constructor is not defined.
Ok, I create one more constructor:

```
public ValuesController(){}
```

And in this case it uses only this constructor and never the one where I should inject unity container.

Please advise.

Comment: Is this a WebAPI project or MVC app that happens to have an API controller.

Comment: This is a MVC project that has API Controller.

Answer (score 1):

Add this in your WebApiConfig:

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        // Routes and other stuff here...

        var container = IocContainer.Instance; // Or any other way to fetch your container.
        config.DependencyResolver = new UnityDependencyResolver(container);
    }
}
```

And if you want the same container you can keep it in a static variable, like so:

```
public static class IocContainer
{
    private static readonly Lazy<IUnityContainer> Container = new Lazy<IUnityContainer>(() =>
    {
        var container = new UnityContainer();
        return container;
    });

    public static IUnityContainer Instance
    {
        get { return Container.Value; }
    }
}
```

More info can be found here:

http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/advanced/dependency-injection

On a sidenote, I can also recommend the nuget-package `Unity.Mvc`. It adds a `UnityWebActivator` and support for `PerRequestLifetimeManager`.

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Unity.Mvc/